# How do you split a string into an array

Tags: bash

This seems like it should be stupid easy but I can't seem to get it to work!  I have a string I want to divide into an array based on new lines.

This below is basically what I'm trying to do.

```
echo $devices
serial1 device
serial2 device

arr=$(magic_function $devices)
echo ${arr[0]}
serial1 device
echo ${arr[1]}
serial2 device
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IFS` (internal field separator) determines how words are split in bash. Unquoted expansions are always split. By default, this is \t, \n, and ' '. You can set it to just \n to have your words split on a newline only.

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(yourfunc "$devices") )
```

Another option on newer versions of bash (4.0+), is the `mapfile` command.

```
mapfile -t arr < <(yourfunc "$devices")
```

Comment: should be an easier way for sure, but it works.  Also I called `unset IFS` when I was done so it wouldn't change for other programs.

Comment: Note that `IFS` is usually set by default, so unsetting it is different than restoring it to its old value.